# Android project with library that uses protobufs NoClassDefFound

Tags: android, protocol-buffers

I am trying to write a library that compiles to a jar file and can be included in an android project however whenever I add protocol buffers to the library it throws the following exception at runtime but not compile time:

`10-18 10:10:10.310 25071-25071/com.example.s.manualinsttest E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                              Process: com.example.s.manualinsttest, PID: 25071
                                                                              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/MyLibrary/Tracemsg$MyProtoContainer$MyProto;
                                                                                  ...`

I have validated that this is a problem with a minimal example where the library consists of:

```
public class MyLibrary{ 
    public static void myMethod(){
        Tracemsg.MyProtoContainer.MyProto proto = Tracemsg.MyProtoContainer.MyProto.newBuilder().setMynumber(5).build();
    }

}
```

And a protocol buffer:

```
syntax = "proto2";
option optimize_for = LITE_RUNTIME;

package ...

message MyProtoContainer {

   message MyProto {
      required uint64 mynumber = 1;
   }

}
```

The library compiles just fine and runs when called from a normal java application however when included as a library I get the previously mentioned exception.  Additionally I have tried decompiling the resulting jar file using jadx-gui and the class is in fact there.

Thank you for the help

Comment: check your dependencies and/or try a clean build

Comment: Thank you for your response, the dependencies appear to be set up correctly as the project compiles and the resulting apk contains the class in question.  I have also observed this in multiple different android apps since I tried to distil it to a minimal exmaple.  I suspect that there is something that I am doing wrong with configuring the protocol buffers themselves that is interacting poorly with the android system.

Edit: also if I remove the protocol buffers from the library then it works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

The solution turned out to be that I was using a Gradle plugin which handled the protobuf inner workings for me and it needed to be configured to compile to the lite version.  I found this snippet of code in https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin/tree/master/testProjectLite which has the following:

```
protobuf {
protoc {
    artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.0.0'
}
plugins {
    javalite {
        artifact = 'com.google.protobuf:protoc-gen-javalite:3.0.0'
    }
}
generateProtoTasks {
    all().each { task ->
        task.builtins {
            remove java
        }
        task.plugins {
            javalite { }
        }
    }
}
}
```

As far as I can tell you aren't supposed to use full protobufs in Android and its a little tricky validating that it didn't fall back to using full protobufs if you don't get everything set up correctly.